# Getting the current game state, and sending it across the internet

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-engine, game-physics

I have some question that need to be answered. I am wondering what would be the difference in performance if I serialize a object and send it across, or if I dump the needed variables and reconstructing the game state on the server end. The reason why I am curious, is because I am creating a game where the physics are handled by both the client and the server and to ensure it is working correctly (and nobody is hacking), I want to know what would be the best course of action.

Some info:
Its a 2D game written in Java with the Libgdx api, I am currently using netty as my network backend.

I have been taking notes from here:
http://gafferongames.com/networked-physics/the-physics-simulation/

Comment: This is a very broad subject and likely off-topic for StackOverflow.  The simple answer is to write the code in the way that feels best for you and then optimize later if it turns out there is a performance problem.  Note that _"serialize an object"_ and _"dump the needed variables and reconstructing the game state on the server end"_ both mean essentially the same thing, but in the first case you use builtin serialization and in the second you write your own serialization code.

Comment: You do raise valid points, it is essentially the same thing, and I was very broad with the wording. I was wondering if serializing would introduce a bottleneck or something since I never worked with it before. But I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim Garrison said, it is a very broad question and you should write your code first and then optimize it later but I will give you few pointers regarding the same.

You can send data in any manner you want and initially it is the matter of what you prefer more. You can start off by using Serializing Java objects and sending them over the network. For Serializing the data I would advise you to use some library like **Kryo** which is very very fast when compared to inbuilt Java serialization. Follow the [link](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) to see performance of various jvm serializers.

For the starting you can user [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) library for writing networking code. Kryonet uses Kryo serializer to serialize your Java objects and send them across network. It's very easy to use too.

Later on you can move on to networking library called [Netty](http://netty.io/) which provides you to write your own protocols. Then as you said you can write some protocol which suits you the most. Pair Netty up with [Google's Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) and you get a really good Networking Library with a top serializer. I am also currently using them both together and I like the way I can define my custom messages using protobuf and the inbuilt support for protobuf which netty provides.

Finally as far as hacking your game is concerned, it should be a completely different question. Once your game becomes a success and you feel people would like to hack your game, you would have gained enough knowledge already to understand how to avoid the same :)

Good luck! I hope the answer pointed you in the right direction.